# xsd complexType without sequence but with several occurrences

Tags: xml, xsd, sequence

I have xml docs similar to this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Structure>
    <Element1>Elementname1</Element1>
    <Element2>Elementname2</Element2>
    <StructureElement>
        <Element2>Elementname4</Element2>
        <Element1>Elementname3</Element1>
        <StructureElement>
            <Element2>Elementname5</Element2>
            <Element1>Elementname6</Element1>
        </StructureElement>
    </StructureElement>
    <StructureElement>
        <Element2>Elementname7</Element2>
        <Element1>Elementname8</Element1>
    </StructureElement>
</Structure>
```

- The elements "Element1" and "Element1" may occur only once, but must occur.
- The element "StructurElement" may occur several times or not at all.
- All elements can occur in any order.

I'm trying to build an XSD for that, but at the moment I can't get any further.

At the moment I have this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="StructureType">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Element1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="Element2" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="StructureElement"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="StructureElementType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Element1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="Element2" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="StructureElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Element1" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Element2" type="xs:string" />

    <xs:element name="Structure" type="StructureType" />
    <xs:element name="StructureElement" type="StructureElementType" />

</xs:schema>
```

But with this code "Element1" or "Element2" can occur more than once.
Do you have any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: I think in the XSD 1.1 version you are allowed e.g. `<xs:all><xs:element name="Element1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><xs:element name="Element2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/><xs:element name="StructureElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/></xs:all>`.

Answer (score 2):

The following XSD 1.1 schema would do, I think:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">
    
    <xs:complexType name="StructureType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Element2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="StructureElement" type="StructureType"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:all>       
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:element name="Structure" type="StructureType"/>
    
</xs:schema>
```

I am not sure there is an XSD 1.0 way to model your constraints and options.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
When I use this XSD, then I get the error message that maxOccurs for "StructureElement" can only be 0 or 1.
Do I have to change anything else?

Comment: As Martin said it's an XSD 1.1 schema so you will need an XSD 1.1 processor. Your requirement can't be met in XSD 1.0.

Comment: @noobinperson, in the Java world http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/ is available, for instance, to do XSD 1.1 validation. I don't know if Oracle has a JRE version that directly integrates an XSD 1.1 compatible version of Xerces. In the .NET world Saxon EE as a validator could help, although it is not open-source, so you would have to buy a license. Various XML IDEs like oXygen or Altova also have support for XSD 1.1, either by integrating Xerces or Saxon or by using their own implementation of XSD 1.1, I think, in the case of Altova.

Comment: Thank you Martin.
At the moment I have to clarify if we can use xml 1.1 or if we have to accept that we have to use xs:sequence and have a strict order in the xml.